# Wordpress update Deadlock

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-deadlocks

I have got a import that will update quite a lot of rows.

From time to time it gets hit by a deadlock.

The question is, how can I catch a deadlock in order to retry this update?

I am using update_post_meta() for this, but I am failing to understand how to try/catch this.

Comment: Guess you must be more specific of what exactly fails, what you want to achieve and what you mean by deadlock in this context ...

Comment: I will try, thou I though that I was quite specific in my explanation above. I have an importer that updates custom meta tags of the custom post type. For each field I have in the importer, after some validation of the field I am running update_post_meta() command. Sometimes MySQL returnes DeadLock message for the update. What I want is NOT to fail in this case but to retry again